# C# how to check array in list

Tags: c#, list, model

I'm building a Worker service for Windows who gets data from another program on the system.
at this point i have all data that is need now i want to keep a list with up to date data.
When i run the application for the Zones i get `System.Int32[]` what i would love to see is the data from `System.Int32[]`

how to obtain this?

```
List<BroadcastModel> activeOmroep = new List<BroadcastModel>();

for (int o = 0; o < webcontent.Length; o++)
        {
       
            for (int i = 0; i < webcontent[o].Zones.Length; i++)
            {
                
            }
            
            activeOmroep.Add(new BroadcastModel
            {
                Id = webcontent[o].Id,
                Name = webcontent[o].Name,
                Recording = webcontent[o].Recording,
                Zones = webcontent[o].Zones
            }) ;
```

My `BroadcastModel` class looks like the following:

```
public class BroadcastModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int[] Channels { get; set; }
    public bool Recording { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int Volume { get; set; }
    public int[] Zones { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

for testing purpose i added the following:

```
foreach (var omroep in activeOmroep)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Broadcast ID: " + omroep.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Broadcast Name: " + omroep.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Broadcast is recording: " + omroep.Recording);
            Console.WriteLine("Broadcast Zones: " + omroep.Zones);
            Console.WriteLine("****************************");
        }
```

but then i got the system.int32[]

Comment: At which portion of code you faced issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you are printing data using `Console.WriteLine()`, it calls `.ToString()` method, if `.ToString()` is not overridden then it calls `Object.ToString()` method. `Object.ToString()` prints type in the string format.

In your case `Console.WriteLine("Broadcast Zones: " + omroep.Zones);` is printing `System.Int32[]`, because it is calling `ToString()` method with the basic behavior.

To solve your issue, I would suggest to `Override` `ToString()` method in `BroadcastModel` class and return string which you want to print.

To print array elements, use [`string.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0) method.

> Concatenates the elements of a specified array or the members of a
> collection, using the specified separator between each element or
> member.

```
public class BroadcastModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int[] Channels { get; set; }
    public bool Recording { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int Volume { get; set; }
    public int[] Zones { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return $"ID : {this.Id}, \nName: {this.Name} \nIs recording: {this.Recording} \nZones : {string.Join(", ", this.Zones)}";
    }
}
```

Now you can print `List<BroadcastModel>` using `foreach` loop,

```
foreach(var broadcastmodel in activeOmroep)
   Console.WriteLine(broadcastmodel);
```

Comment: @SanderBloem, I updated my answer to give you more clarity on why you were getting `System.Int32[]`